# Notepad2 horizontal scrolling issue

Tags: scrolling, scrollbar, notepad2

I love Notepad2, but the one thing that is starting to make me want to ditch it is the horizontal scrolling quirk that prevents you from using the scrollbar to scroll all the way out to the right in text files with very long lines.  You can still scroll, but you have to click the arrow on the scroll bar to get it to work.  I know that you can also disable wrapping, but I don't want to do that for various reasons which are irrelevant here.  I also tried tilting my mouse wheel, but it stops scrolling when the end of the horizontal scrollbar has been reached.

Research as lead me to posts where people just chalk it up to "that's the way it is".  Either that or I see a bunch of apologetics about why it's *supposed* to be that way.

So I am coming to StackExchange to see if any of you power users can attest that this is truly by design or if there is a way around it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's caused by the Scintilla editing component.

> Notepad2 FAQ: **[Why is the horizontal scrollbar not calculated properly?](http://www.flos-freeware.ch/doc/notepad2-FAQs.html#q23)**
>
> As one single line may contain many different syntax styles, proper line length calculation requires high performance. For this reason, a fixed width is assumed. The end of long lines can always be reached using the End key or the scrollbar arrows.

According to [Scintilla's website](http://www.scintilla.org/ScintillaHistory.html), however, this has been fixed in release 1.75

> **Release 1.75**
>
> - The horizontal scroll bar may grow to match the widest line displayed.

So it used to be "by design", but seems to be fixable now. But if you want the most reliable answer, contact the developer of Notepad2 and ask them if this could be implemented.